# How to make Text Editor like Codepen

Tags: javascript, html, css, clone, codepen

**Hi Everyone!**
I want to make an editor for my website with functions like ***working light/dark toggle button***, ***Working editor that really shows the result*** and ***Syntax Hilighting***. I have made the frame of the editor...

```js
function compile(){
    var html = document.getElementById("html");
    var css = document.getElementById("css");
    var js = document.getElementById("js");
    var code = document.getElementById("code").contentWindow.document;

    document.body.onkeyup = function(){
        code.open();
        code.writeln(html.value+"<style>"+css.value+"<\/style>" + "<script>"+js.value+"<\/script>")
        code.close();
    }
}
compile();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 20px;          
}
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #444444; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {   
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: #666666;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.25), inset -2px -2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {     
  background-color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,#ff1010,#201c29 1px,#100e17 1px,#100e17);
}
textarea ::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 8px;          
}

textarea ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {   
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: #666666;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.25), inset -2px -2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}

textarea ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {     
  background-color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,#ff1010,#201c29 1px,#100e17 1px,#100e17);
}
header#playground_header {
  background: #1e1f26;
  height: 65px;
}
header#playground_header > h1 {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sens-serif;
}
iframe#code {
  bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vh;
  border: unset;
  background: #f2f4f6;
}
.prism-live {
  min-height: 350px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
div#coding_area > div {
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 15px solid #555865;
}
div#coding_area > div:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
div#coding_area {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(60vh - 60px);
  min-height: 125px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #555865;
}
textarea {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000000;
}
div#code_output {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Coding Playground | #Programmer</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Sans:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css">
  <script src="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
  <script src="https://codemirror.net/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
  <script src="https://codemirror.net/mode/css/css.js"></script>
  <script src="https://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="coding_playground_outer">
    <header id="playground_header">
      <h1>Coding Playground | #Programmer</h1>
    </header>
    <hr color="#fff">
    <div class="page-wrap twilight">
      <div class="boxes">
        <div id="coding_area">
          <textarea id="html" placeholder="HTML" class="prism-live language-html"></textarea>
          <textarea id="css" placeholder="CSS" class="prism-live language-css"></textarea>
          <textarea id="js" placeholder="JavaScript" class="prism-live language-js"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div id="code_output">
          <iframe id="code"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<body>
```

This code is 65% working as I imagined it. Just need a working toggle light/dark switch button now and a Syntax Hilight. Please help me as soon as possible...

Comment: You should take a look at the [Monaco Editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/monaco-editor)

Comment: @PEPEGA - I want to make my own code editor... Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: _"Please help me as soon as possible..."_ [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) TLDR; Never

Comment: Syntax highlighting for which languages?

Comment: html css and js

Comment: Do you have a parser for these languages?

Comment: what is the meaning of parser? I don't know because i am a beginner

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @lupz - The question is

Comment: @lupz - I have a code shown above. Just answer that->1. How to male a light / dark toggle button ... 2. Syntax Hilight the code... Thats all.

Comment: 1. Give the `body` a class. Toggle it with the button between `'light'` and `'dark'`. Add css styles for both states. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/j573y4bg/) is an example.

Comment: 2. Do you want to write your own parser or use a library? In either case this is too broad for an answer and you should describe your approach. How to write a parser is a topic for a whole book.

Comment: I suggest to read the code of some open source editors to get some ideas and learn how this can be solved.

Comment: @jabaa - can i use prism.js library for my editor

Comment: @jabaa - https://jsfiddle.net/Coders_Champ/c5z9tgrf/

Comment: @jabaa - link of the design of toggle button

Comment: Yes, you can use it.